# Search CSV for IP's in a List

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python and can't seem to get this to work. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I have a list of IP address and I would like to search a CSV for any matches and print rows from csv that have the IP addresses from the list.

list = ['103.13.228.134', '104.41.140.0' , '118.102.64.126']

```
with open('.\\input\\%s' % x, 'rt') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for i in list:
            if i in row:
                print row
```

CSV contains multiple fields example below:

Source/Destination/Service

'192.168.0.0','101.200.81.187','SSH'

Comment: `for i in list:` are you defining a variable called `list` because with the built in `list` this gives an error.  please provide a [Minimal Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: is each column in the csv an IP? or what? We can't help you unless you show a sample of what you're actually reading in. and note that "ip address" is vague. maybe you mean a dotted quad (e.g. 127.0.0.1), but note that 7f000001 is a valid IP as well, since that's just 127.0.0.1 in hex form.

Comment: My apologists added edits with more information.

Answer (score 0):

try `pandas` for it. Assuming your IP addresses are stored in the column `"IPadd"`

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")
addresses = data["IPadd"]
list_of_valid_ip = ['103.13.228.134', '104.41.140.0' , '118.102.64.126']
selected = data[addresses.isin(list_of_valid_ip)]
print(selected)
```

Comment: f = open('file.csv', 'rt')
data = pd.read_csv(f)
addresses = data["Source IP"]
list_of_valid_IP = list
selected = data[addresses.isin(list_of_valid_IP)]
print(selected)                                                                                   Thanks for answer! code  above produces. Error Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Total, Sent(MB), Received(MB), Hits, User, Group, Source IP, Source Name, Destination IP, Destination Name, Service]
Index: []